# Most reliable way to check for connected client?

Tags: embedded, ethernet, ping

I have an embedded Linux OS developed from scratch using Yocto. This talks to a Windows XP/7 client. The embedded OS runs a DHCP server and gives an address to the client. The problem is that the client is "locked down" and blocks many standard ports and methods of doing things. If the client is detected present by the embedded system, my startup script will launch the server that tests the system; otherwise I kexec to another OS. **What is the best way to detect if a client connected over Ethernet is there on startup (in Linux)  without adding significant bootup time to the system?**

Here are the things I've tried and what does not work:

1. ICMP packets are blocked on the client side so traditional pinging does not work
2. arping works (as well as nmap using ARP scan) but Windows clients try to be "smart" and dial out so it takes 20-25 seconds to actually establish the connection, which is unacceptable; ideally, it should detect something in 5-10 seconds. Is there anything I can set on the server side to speed this up? It always boots into this partition first so the quickest solution is the best solution.
3. ifplugd, ethtool, netplugd, and probing /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate and /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier do not work because the Ethernet port on the embedded system is connected to an internal switch so it is always "up" and "connected" hardware wise
4. A future solution will likely use Bonjour on the client side and Avahi on the server so we can have a connectionless protocol, but this will take time to implement and I need an interim solution because any software we add to the client side takes a very long time to get approval for.

Again, I can't do anything on the client side because these units are configured by another company and locked down. So what else can I try on the server to detect if the client is present?

Comment: Any suggestions at all would be appreciated; I'm seriously out of ideas. I've also tried all the solutions here and at serverfault as well.

Answer (score 1):

So, you said there's an internal switch. Are you able to access that switch's management? Either by I2C (embedded switch) or SNMP?

You state your embedded OS runs a DHCP server. If a client makes a DHCP request, isn't that proof that the client is present and reachable?

I have no idea what you mean by "smart" and "dialing out." If the windows machine is going to communicate on the ethernet at all, it needs to respond to ARP. So far, arping seems like the best option.

Comment: It's a dumb switch, so more of a hub. I don't have much specs on it other than two interfaces in it are connected together on the same subnet (192.168.1.*) via a switch. Checking for a DHCP request isn't the most ideal; I was checking for this in /var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases but this was not reliable either. And what I mean by smart is that even when it's a LAN, Windows machines try to establish a WAN connection so it keeps trying to connect and eventually goes to a limited connectivity state at which point it finally says "OK, this is only a LAN connection, I'm finally up".

Comment: By the way, I agree polling the switch would be the best solution but I wouldn't know where to start with that. Any GNU Linux tool for probing switch parameters? I only know of swconfig from OpenWRT.

I'm going to install the iproute2 package and see if ip neigh is any better. Being an embedded system, I am currently using busybox arping.

Comment: You have complete control over the system, so don't limit yourself. You've got the source to the the dhcp daemon in use, so find the logic where it responds to a DHCP request, and modify it to suit your needs? That function could invoke a command or set a flag? Also, there's a possibility you could directly poll your switch - this is a crude way to gauge the level of integration, but do the ethernet switch and your embedded CPU share a PCB - are they all part of one circuit board?